# Add Entry to Calendar iOS - Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm trying to create a new entry in the calendar from my application on iOS.
I have the following code:

```
    public void AddEvent(String eventTitle, String eventDescription, DatePicker eventBegin, String repeat)
    {
        RequestAccess();
        EKEventStore eventStore = new EKEventStore();

        Foundation.NSDate nsDate = (NSDate)eventBegin.Date;
        DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)nsDate;
        Foundation.NSError ex = null;

        var StartDate = nsDate.ToString();

        try
        {
            EKEvent newEvent = EKEvent.FromStore(eventStore);
            newEvent.StartDate = nsDate;
            newEvent.EndDate = nsDate;
            newEvent.Title = eventTitle;
            newEvent.Notes = eventDescription;
            newEvent.Calendar = eventStore.DefaultCalendarForNewEvents;
            eventStore.SaveEvent(newEvent, EKSpan.ThisEvent, true, out ex);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

But my app is closing when I call this function, I have debugged it, and there is no Exception thrown.
The Application Output looks like this:

```
Thread started:  #11
2020-10-07 12:06:20.141477+0300 MasseyFeeds.iOS[1692:95841] [EventKit] Error getting default calendar for new events: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013 "(null)"
2020-10-07 12:06:20.141647+0300 MasseyFeeds.iOS[1692:95841] [EventKit] No object ID provided.  Will not find out if the object exists.
Thread started:  #12
2020-10-07 12:06:29.248546+0300 MasseyFeeds.iOS[1692:95841] [Common] _BSMachError: port 14d03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2020-10-07 12:06:29.249561+0300 MasseyFeeds.iOS[1692:95841] [Common] _BSMachError: port 14d03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
```

Any idea why I'm getting this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> `Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1013`

You have to request user approval access to the calendar.

> If your app has never requested access before, you must request access to events or reminders before attempting to fetch or create them. If you request data before prompting the user for access with this method, you'll need to reset the event store with the reset method in order to start receiving data after the user grants access.

- Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507547-requestaccesstoentitytype
- Xamarin docs, remarks Section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/eventkit.ekeventstore?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#remarks

## Example from Xamarin docs:

```
App.Current.EventStore.RequestAccess (EKEntityType.Event, 
    (bool granted, NSError e) => {
        if (granted)
            //do something here
        else
            new UIAlertView ( "Access Denied", 
"User Denied Access to Calendar Data", null,
"ok", null).Show ();
        } );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've tried in this way and is not working. `granted` is true, my code gets accessed but there is no action. I'm getting this: `2020-10-08 12:25:15.790487+0300 MasseyFeeds.iOS[3488:223909] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=3488`.

Comment: @ClaudiuL93 Lots of `SecTaskLoadEntitlements` error=22 info, google/bing it